# widely used formula for DCG seems to be wrong?

Tags: search-engine, metrics, information-retrieval

There are two widely used formulas (found in most Information retrieval lecture slides on the internet, e.g. [at Stanford](http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs276/handouts/EvaluationNew-handout-6-per.pdf)) for computing the Discounted Cumulative Gain. One of them is, for the DCG at rank p:

[image: first formula]

This is, in fact:

[image]

Because log_2(2) = 1. This means that the so-called "discounted" CG is actually not discounted before the third rank!

The following rankings are therefore not distinguishable by the DCG using this formula: (10,5,1,2,...) and (5,10,1,2,...).

I am guessing that the formula is incorrect and should be:

[image]

Note btw that the other very common formula (see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discounted_cumulative_gain#Discounted_Cumulative_Gain)) has this denominator.

I would not be asking if I hadn't seen this formula in practically all the lectures I found on the internet and even in my own lectures at UCL. Is it not wrong? It would be incredible that an error has propagated from Wikipedia and not been picked up by the professors... Am I wrong then?

Comment: It's better to use the other function \sum (2^rel_i - 1)/log(i+1)... The other thing that can be done is to change the base of the logarithm (to say e.. the natural log).. However, in all practical scenarios the original formula would work because it is more likely for two lists (say of size 1000) to differ in ranks beyond 2 than within 2....

Comment: Agreed, but this is no argument. It is also more likely for two lists (say of size 1000) to differ in ranks beyond 3 than within 3, so why not start discounting at rank 3 only?

Comment: Also, I don't know if it is "better" to use the other formula, they are, after all, two different formulas, and the one you propose makes at lot of sense for rel between 0 and 1. My rel scores are between 0 and infinity so manipulating 2^rel is really impractical.

Comment: rel scores can't (in practice) be infinite... it has to be a finite number (and that too typically small say from 0 to 4)

Comment: My rel scores range from 0 to Infinity, which does not mean any of them are actually Infinity, but that they have no upper bound. in practice, they very rarely go over 1000. But 2^1024=Inf in my programming language!

Answer (score 2):

I found [this paper from Microsoft](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/tesakai/metrics.pdf) (see equation 6) which backs up my claim that it is basically a typo start discounting at rank 3 only. When you think of it, it makes no sense at all to not discount the rank 2! The metric would be unable to distinguish the rankings (10, 5, 2) and (5, 10, 2), when the first ranking is better. Note that all the other DCG formulas do discount rank 2 and thus would pick up a difference.

So a "+1" is indeed missing in the log, and it is a typo which has been creeping in a lot of papers and lectures...